# Is there any true general pattern to solve any dynamic programming problems?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, dynamic-programming

I understand there is a general pattern to solve dynamic programming problems. Consists of:

1. Identify Overlapping Subproblem by Breaking down the problem into smaller subproblems that are solved independently.
2. Memoization by Creating a data structure to store the solutions to subproblems usually hash map
3. Initialize Base Cases to Identify the base cases or trivial subproblems and initialize their solutions
4. Fill in the Memoization Table by Iterate through the subproblems
5. Finally, Return the Final Solution.

Once the memoization table is filled, the solution to the problem can often be found in the table's last entry or in a specific entry that represents the desired outcome.

However, it is applicable to simpler problems only such as the fibonacci problem in the below code.

```
def fibonacci(n, memo={}):
    if n in memo:
        return memo[n]
    if n <= 1:
        return n
    
    result = fibonacci(n - 1, memo) + fibonacci(n - 2, memo)
    memo[n] = result
    return result

# Example usage
n = 10
print(f"The {n}-th Fibonacci number is: {fibonacci(n)}")
```

Do we required to train ourself solving a lot of Dynamic programming problems to see the pattern that applicable to solve any Dynamic programming problem at any scale, any complexities? or there is a secret formula which can be replicated?

I try to find general pattern that replicable to solve any dynamic programming problem in Python

Comment: Well, there are Bottom-up and top-down patterns. I think there is no magic formula that can solve any dynamic programming problem. You need to train yourself to understand the problem so get used to identifying subproblems from a complex problem.

Comment: So, there is no pattern that we can recognize when identifying subproblems? Is that mean everyone can approach the problem with different solution but getting same results?

Comment: @silenoksweet "everyone can approach the problem with different solution but getting same results" I'd say that's true about most of problems in programming. If the interviewer is expecting a single golden solution from you, it probably means they are pretty bad themselves and memorized a problem, instead of learning how to build solutions for various problems. And most people, I'd guess over 90% won't need to solve a single DP problem in their career, just the same as they won't need to implement any sorting algos. It's good to do so as a practice when studying, but that's it imho.

Answer (score 0):

no. in general you should try to model the problem so that you can make the dynamic programming array from it. if you could do it (memoized or bottom up) then you have it.no. in general you should try to model the problem so that you can make the dynamic programming array from it. if you could do it (memoized or bottom up) then you have it.